# How to change currency position in Angular locale data?

Tags: angular, internationalization

So our client is Norwegian (`nb`, not `nn`) and wants the currency symbol to display on the right like `nn` does. (Changing `nb` to `nn` is not an option.)

I was wondering if I can monkey patch the locale data for `nb`, but it doesn't look like I can.

I was also thinking of monkey patching `getLocaleNumberFormat` method which Angular uses internally, but not quite sure how to do it with ES2015 imports. ):

Any other clever solution, before I create my own pipe?

Answer (score 1):

you should add hidden div based on following condition

```js
     // use getLocaleNumberFormat, check currency symbol position
     
     const currencyFormat = getLocaleNumberFormat(this.locale, NumberFormatStyle.Currency);
      this.currencyPrefix = currencyFormat.startsWith('¤');
```

```html
<div class="d-flex form-control-composed">
        <div [hidden]="!currencyPrefix" class="position-absolute mt-2 ml-2">
                {{currencyValue}}
        </div>
        <!--suppress HtmlFormInputWithoutLabel -->
        <input type="text"
               igxInput
               [igxMask]="mask"
               #fixedNumber
               name="value"
               [(ngModel)]="value"
               [readOnly]="componentConfiguration?.readOnly"
               [required]="componentConfiguration?.required"
               (keyup)="validateFixedNumber(fixedNumber, $event)">
        <div [hidden]="currencyPrefix" class="position-absolute mt-2 mr-2">
            {{currencyValue}}
        </div>
    </div>
```